# Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 carousel: infinite loop after last slide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was just asked by one of my customers to change his existing twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 carousel to an infinite loop.
Just now it does not slide from the last to the first slide but it actually loads the whole image so it looks kinda choppy when the last slide is reached.

I was not able to find anything helpful related to this neither on google nor here so:
Is there such a feature even existing for the bootstrap 2.3.2 carousel? Is there any easy way to achieve or implement this?
I even want to avoid exchanging the whole carousel or move to bootstrap 3 or anything else :)

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should do this by default, read the docs http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel

Comment: Paste your existing code so we can see if you made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you were right, I had to check more deeply before. There was everything right with the carousel but not with the CSS code...
The guy who implemented this tried to change the slide behavior to vertical with CSS but there was an error causing the last not to fade out but to disappear.

Thanks anyways!